# Automatically update the Navigation Property of other side of a relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I have the following data model using Entity Framework 6.0:

[image: Data Model]

To create the entity classes I use the EF6.x DbContext Generator. It creates a file for `MyTable1` and `MyTable2`, declaring their Navigation Property as HashSet.

The ObjectContext Generator I used before created an EntityCollection instead of a HashSet and the classes it created inherited from EntityObject.

Now, I have this code:

```
var myTable2 = new MyTable2();
var myTable1 = new MyTable1();
myTable1.MyTable2.Add(myTable2);
```

`myTable2` is now added to the `MyTable2` Navigation Property of `myTable1`. `myTable1` is not added to the Navigation Property of `myTable2`.

When I used the ObjectContext Generator, EF set the `MyTable1` Navigation Property of `myTable2` automatically to `myTable1`.
Since I switched to the DbContext Generator this does not happen any more.

When I have a DbContext with these objects added I could call DetectChanges(). But:

- I sometimes use these classes (e.g. in unit tests) without creating a DbContext.
- I am updating a lot of old code and it would take quite a while to check it all and find out where to add a DetectChanges() call.

Is there a way to make EF automatically update the Navigation Property of the other side of a relation as soon as it is changed on one side?

**EDIT:**

According to the comments, I learned that without a `DbContext` I have to update the Navigation Properties on the other side manually.

If using a `DbContext` I tried using proxies so I can omit the `DetectChanges()` calls. I made all properties (not only the Navigation Properties) virtual and removed the Navigation Property (HashSet) initialisation from the constructor.

The code snippet now uses the `Create()` method to instantiate objects:

```
using (var context = new EFTestEntities())
{
    context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
    context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;

    var myTable2 = context.MyTable2.Create();
    var myTable1 = context.MyTable1.Create();

    myTable1.MyTable2.Add(myTable2);
}
```

`myTable2` now gets the Navigation Property link to `myTable1`. But the foreign key to `myTable1` does not get updated - even if I call `DetectChanges()`. What is still missing here?

Comment: By default, changes are detected automatically... but if they are not for some reason, you need to use: `context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;`. Make sure your generated navigation properties are `virtual` and that you have proxies enabled: `context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;`

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. AutoDetectChangesEnabled and ProxCreationEnabled are both set to true and the Navigation Properties are both virtual already.

Comment: create the entities using the context then: when you use `new`, no proxies are created and the system is just using your POCOs (which don't have any tracking code in them)... use: `context.NameOfYourMyTable1Set.Create()` instead of `new MyTable1()`, etc.

Comment: Thank you. See my updated post.

Comment: ok, I see the problem... I misread the question, I thought you were saying it did not happen at all... yes, it won't happen till you call `DetectChanges()` or `SaveChanges()` (auto detect just calls detectchanges automatically when saving changes). I recall a discussion about this somewhere on the MSDN forums and MS saying it was because of performance reasons (the not updating automatically), so I don't think it's possible in EF6's DbContext without calling `DetectChanges` (or `SaveChanges` or similar)

Comment: Thank you very much. So if I don't have a DbContext I have to add myTable1 manually to myTable2.MyTable1?

Comment: yes... AFAIK for EF6, unless you are detecting changes on the dbcontext, you need to assign navigation properties manually

Comment: I made the properties virtual and removed the Navigation Property (HashSet) initialisation from the constructor. Now `myTable2` gets the Navigation Property link to `myTable1` even without calling `DetectChanges()` - due to the change tracking proxy I assume. But it does not get the foreign key to `myTable1` updated until I call `SaveChanges()`.

Comment: Yes, but you do need a `DbContext` for it (to generate the proxies for you), I thought your problem (as stated in the last comment) was you didn't have a DbContext. If you do, then yes, it should work if your object is created (and populated) by the `DbContext`, and not by using `new`